# How to select items from JSON returned by AXIOS get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm trying to `res.send()` the first movie details from the JSON file returned by `axios.get()`.
But I'm not able to select the item. Please show me the way to select and `res.send()` the first movie details from the JSON file which I got.

This is my node.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
app = express()
const axios = require('axios')

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.send("You are in the Home Page!!")
})

app.get("/result", function(req,res){
  (async () => {
    try{
      const response = await axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=guardians+of+the+galaxy&apikey=thewdb')
      // result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      var result = response.data
      res.send(result.search[0])
    } catch (error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  })()
  // res.send("Hello it works")
})

app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('Movie app has Started');
})
```

This is the JSON file that is got:

```
// 20200709131745
// http://localhost:3000/result

{
  "Search": [
    {
      "Title": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
      "Year": "2014",
      "imdbID": "tt2015381",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAwMjU5OTgxNjZeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDUxNDYxODEx._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2",
      "Year": "2017",
      "imdbID": "tt3896198",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjM0NTc0NzItM2FlYS00YzEwLWE0YmUtNTA2ZWIzODc2OTgxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTgwNzIyNzg@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "totalResults": "11",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

Expected output:

```
      "Title": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
      "Year": "2014",
      "imdbID": "tt2015381",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAwMjU5OTgxNjZeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDUxNDYxODEx._V1_SX300.jpg"
```

Comment: i think it will be res.send(result.Search[0]). Capital S in search

Comment: ok. Got it
Thank you

Comment: And if you want to send JSON data with `Content-Type: application/json`, you can use `res.json(result.Search[0])` instead